# Не отображается ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Пытаюсь загрузить картинку из ресурса и вывести её в Imageview после чего програмно добавить его в Layout

```
LinearLayout tmp_layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
tmp_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
tmp_layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
tmp_layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
linearLayout.addView(tmp_layout, params);

TextView textView = new TextView(MessagesActivity.this);
textView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
//textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.background_message_from);
//textView.setText(message_enc_from_key);
textView.setText(decrypt(hex2Byte(message_enc_from_key), private_key_my));
//textView.setText(date_time);
textView.setTextSize(20);
tmp_layout.addView(textView, params);

ImageView tmp_img = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
tmp_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_face_black_24dp);
tmp_layout.addView(tmp_img, params);
```

Проблема в том что textview отображается, а imageview нет. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Попробуйте MessagesActivity.this вместо getApplicationContext() использовать

Comment: А ещё можно попробовать параметры высоты ширины жёстко задать. А ещё может просто на экран не влезло

Comment: "Попробуйте MessagesActivity.this вместо getApplicationContext()" не помогает

Comment: строка `tmp_layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));` не имеет у вас никакого эффекта, т. к. вы после этого добавляете `tmp_layout` с новыми параметрами: `linearLayout.addView(tmp_layout, params);`